# String Length validation php form

Tags: php, forms, validation

This is my code to check if the field is empty and it works fine, however i want to check for both, if its empty and if its got less than 10 characters

```
<pre>
        if(empty($_POST['comments'])){ $errors[]="Please enter a comment."; }
</pre>
```

I tried this

```
<pre>
        if(empty($_POST['comments'])){ $errors[]="Please enter a comment."; }
        if(strlen($_POST['comments']) > 10){ $errors[]="Please enter a comment."; }
</pre>
```

However this then made neither work so i tried which had the same result with neither of them working

```
<pre>
        if(empty($_POST['comments']) && strlen($_POST['comments']) > 10)){ $errors[]="Your 
         comment must be longer than 10 characters."; }
</pre>
```

I have tried mb_strlen as well but that changed nothing.

Comment: Your strlen comparison is backwards. You're doing, "if length is greater than 10, then issue an error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off. You're currently adding the error if the string is empty *and longer* than 10 characters (which would be a paradox.)

You need to check if the string is empty *or less* then 10 characters.

Try this:

```
if (empty($_POST['comments']) || strlen($_POST['comments']) < 10) {
    $errors[] = "Your comment must be longer than 10 characters.";
}
```

That condition checks if the string is either empty *or* if the string has less `<` than 10 characters.

`&&` means *and*
`||` means *or*
`<` means *less than*
`>` means *greater than*

You can read more about [logical](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in the manual.